# Why the AppLifeCycleStates events are not invoked in android 12 emulator/device?

Tags: android, flutter

OK here is the code. I just modified the boilerplate code that comes when opening a new flutter project.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  int _counter = 0;
  //////////////////////////FOCUS HERE/////////////////////////
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('app resumed');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print('app inactive');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print('app paused');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        print('app detached');
        break;
    }
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In my emulator running android 11, when i minimize the app emulator

[image: Emulator minimized]

I get these statements printed on my console

[image: Console output on emulator minimize]

I get 'app resumed statement printed' on my console when I resume emulator

[image: On Emulator REsume]

**But I dont get any output in the console of my ANDROID 12 EMULATOR why??**

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add an ensureinitialized function in main like this

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```